# Deviations from mean for sum of Bernoulli

Tags: probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I have the following problem in my work, which reduces after some modelisation to the following:

Consider random values $(X_t)_t\ge 1$ iid uniform over $\{1,.., h\}$.

I am interested in the random variable $$ T=\min_{1\le k\le h} cardinal \left\{
i\in\{1,..,t_{max}\} : X_t=k
\right\}$$

The intuition is that, for a given value of $t_{max}$, the $X_i$ will be well distributed enough should $T$  be small.

The problem is: determine $t$ such as $P(T>t) < \epsilon$. I'm ok with an approximate formula.

Here is what I got to:

- trivial bounds $t_{max}/h \le T \le t_{max}$
- for $h=2$: the problem reduces to the following: given $X_i$ iid with law Bernoulli with $p=1/2$,

$$
P(T>t) = P\left(\left| \sum_{t=1}^{t_{max}} X_i - \frac{t_{max}}2 \right| > \delta
\right), \delta=t-\frac {t_{max}}2
$$

From the central limit theorem, I can deduce the approximations
$$
P(T>t) \approx P(\left| N(0,1) \right|>  2 \sqrt {t_{max}} \delta )
\\
t \approx \frac{t_{max}}2 + \sqrt{t_{max}} \frac{\alpha_{\epsilon/2} }2
$$

where $\alpha_\epsilon$ is read from a table.

Any idea how to generalize that for $h>2$?

Comment: This might be easier to understand with words, using Upper Case for Random Variables and lower case for constants.  I think you are asking for the distribution of $T$ the number of balls in the least occupied bin when you throw $m$ (your $t_\max$) balls  into $n$ (your $H$) bins independently uniformly at random.  If so, you might find some of the comments at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135804/balls-and-bins-concentration-bounds-pertaining-to-the-minimal-load-bin helpful

Comment: thanks @Henry for the reference! I indeed changed variables to better fit usual notations.

Comment: I think you still have several $H$ that are supposed to be $h$ ?

Comment: thanks @Evargalo, indeed.